# Creating a namespace to "import" a database class in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, class, namespaces, .net-2.0

I need to create a namespace for my database class file, so I can call the database procedures within my webservice module. How can I create a namespace to call that Db class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like there's more to this question than I'm reading...

Namespaces in VB.NET occur at two levels.

The top level (default) namespace can be found in the project properties on the Application tab. All the namespaces defined in your project will belong to the default namespace.

For each class you can define a namespace with the following syntax:

```
Import System

Namespace MyNamespace.MySubNamespace

    Public Class MyClass

    End Class

End Namespace
```

The full namespace of the class will be DefaultNamespace.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace